# Linq Query If statement

Tags: vb.net, linq

Ok im trying to do a if statement in Linq and was wondering if it was possible to do something like:

```
            Dim loadFriends = From p In db.UserRelationships Where p.aspnet_User.UserName = User.Identity.Name _
                          Or p.aspnet_User1.UserName = User.Identity.Name And p.Type = 1 _
                          Select New With {if p.aspnet_user1.user = "a certan username" then .username = _
                                          p.aspnet_user.username else .username = p.aspnet_user1.Username}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks tyrongower

here is the query if anyone else has this same problem:

```
Dim loadFriends = From p In db.UserRelationships Where p.aspnet_User.UserName = User.Identity.Name _
                          Or p.aspnet_User1.UserName = User.Identity.Name And p.Type = 1 _
                          Select New With {.username = If((p.aspnet_User1.UserName = User.Identity.Name), p.aspnet_User.UserName, p.aspnet_User1.UserName)}
```

Comment: That depends a lot on the data source. Are you useing Linq to SQL, Linq to Objects, or something else?

Comment: hi guffa im using linq to sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know VB but in c# is would be

```
 username = (p.aspnet_user1.user == "a certan username")? aspnet_user.username:p.aspnet_user1.Username
```

I assume there would be ternary syntax for VB.NET

Comment: The VB.NET equivalent is the IFF statement:

    Iff(p.aspnet_user1.user = "a certain username", aspnet_user.username, p.aspnet_user1.Username)

Comment: @avanek, better to use the IF operator (spelled with only a single I) as it short circuits although in this case, there's probably not much difference.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway, I didn't know that, thanks for the head's up!

Comment: Minor correction: I think @avanek is talking about [IIf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) (eye-eye-eff) and not IFF (eye-eff-eff). If there is an eye-eff-eff I can't manage to find it on the MSDN site.